# Generating the callgraph of mozilla-central- Error running Valgrind: Launch failed. Binary not found

Tags: macos, firefox, profiling, valgrind, eclipse-cdt

I have downloaded mozilla-central (Nightly) and built it and I am able to open the project in Eclipse CPP and run the application.

My goal is to have access to the call graph of one use-case scenario in Firefox. For instance, I would like to run the application and for the scenario "How to clear my history" on Firefox, I want to take all 3 steps that are mentioned [here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/deletebrowsing-%20search-download-history-firefox).

This is done while a profiler is enabled. Then, I need to analyze the call graph to see what parts of the source code are touched when the scenario was being executed.

My current roadblock is the profiler! When I want to use Valgrind I get an error saying failed to launch, the binary was not found. When I open the project in Eclipse I get an error saying searching for binaries Gecko has encountered a problem. Also, Xcode Instruments was not useful for the task that I am working on.

I just need to parse the source code and analyze how certain scenarios are implemented. I need a profiler (something like Xdebug for PHP) that gives me all the method calls (and their related source code files).

I am working on a Mac and the OS is Sierra Version 10.13.6.

Comment: Can you clarify how you are trying to use Valgrind? You say "When I want to use Valgrind I get an error saying failed to launch, the binary was not found.", but it's not clear what steps you are taking leading up to that error.

Comment: In project explorer: I right click on Gecko --> profiling tools --> profile with Valgrind.
Then I get the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get the same error as you on Linux. My guess is that the Eclipse project would need some additional configuration for this to work, such as defining a launch configuration in `Project Properties | Run/Debug Settings`.

However, taking a step back, note that Firefox has its own **[built-in profiler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Performance/Profiling_with_the_Built-in_Profiler)** which is likely to give more useful information than any third-party profiler. I would suggest giving that a try.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I need  to profile C++ code as well, which is not enabled in the built-in profiler.

Comment: @ResearchStudent You can, in fact, profile C++ code if you install the "Gecko Profiler add-on" linked on that page.

Comment: Yes, I was using the developer tools! This one is muche better. Thanks.